# Can anyone give me sample for gdoc for android using google api client for java?

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-docs

I am currently working on an app for android which needs google docs api? Can any one give me sample of how to use google-api-java-client? I am new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

All of the sample code related to [google api clients are available here.](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample%253Fstate%253Dclosed)